# C# BFS - get node property data from object

Tags: c#, breadth-first-search

Copnsole app.
I have Person object its created from Name and Address objects.
How can I get the person name on path? I get the fullName "to" path is successufuly but not "from" full path , also get destination is successufuly.

Console:

shortest path to aa AA: **BFS_Shortest_Path.Person**, and destination is 0
shortest path to bb BB: **BFS_Shortest_Path.Person, BFS_Shortest_Path.Person**, and destination is 1
shortest path to cc CC: **BFS_Shortest_Path.Person, BFS_Shortest_Path.Person, BFS_Shortest_Path.Person**, and destination is 2

BFS_Shortest_Path.Person - must be fullName of person

Address.cs

```
    {
        private string street;
        private string city;

        public Address(string street, string city)
        {
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
        }

        public string getStreet()
        {
            return street;
        }

        public string getCity()
        {
            return city;
        }
    }
```

Name.cs

```
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public Name(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        public string getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public string getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
    }
```

Person.cs

```
public class Person
    {
        private Name fullName;
        private Address address;

        public Person(Name fullName, Address address)
        {
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.address = address;
        }
        public Name getFullName()
        {
            return fullName;
        }

        public Address getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Name nameA = new Name("aa", "AA");
            Name nameB = new Name("bb", "BB");
            Name nameC = new Name("bb", "BB");
            Name nameD = new Name("cc", "CC");
            Name nameE = new Name("cc", "CC");           

            Address addressA = new Address("b", "B");
            Address addressB = new Address("b", "B");
            Address addressC = new Address("c", "C");           

            Person person1 = new Person(nameA, addressA);
            Person person2 = new Person(nameB, addressB);
            Person person3 = new Person(nameC, addressC);                  

            Person personNotConnect = new Person(nameX, addressX);

            Person[] peoples = new Person[]{person1, person2, person3, personNotConnect};                         

            var edgesPerson = new[]{Tuple.Create(person1,person2), Tuple.Create(person1,person3),Tuple.Create(person3,personNotConnect)};

            var peopleGraph = new Graph<Person>(peoples, edgesPerson);            
            var node = new Node();
             var startVertex = person1;
            var shortestPath = node.ShortestPathFunction(peopleGraph, startVertex);
            var max_steps = 0;
            foreach (var vertex in peoples)
            {
                var fullName = vertex.getFullName().getFirstName() + " " + vertex.getFullName().getLastName();
                max_steps = shortestPath(vertex).Count() - 1;
                Console.WriteLine("shortest path to {0}: {1}, and destination is {2} ",
                        fullName, string.Join(", ", shortestPath(vertex)), shortestPath(vertex).Count() - 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("MAX_STEPS:" + max_steps);
}
```

Graph.cs

```
public class Graph<T>
    {
        public Graph()
        {

        }
        public Graph(IEnumerable<T> vertices, IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> edges)
        {
            foreach (var vertex in vertices)
            {
                AddVertex(vertex);
            }
               
            foreach (var edge in edges)
            {
                AddEdge(edge);
            }
        }
        //The keys are the vertices/node and the value of each vertex is its set of neighbors
        public Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> AdjacencyList { get; } = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();       
        //add set of neighbors
        private void AddEdge(Tuple<T, T> edge)
        {
            if (AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(edge.Item1) && AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(edge.Item2))
            {
                AdjacencyList[edge.Item1].Add(edge.Item2);
                AdjacencyList[edge.Item2].Add(edge.Item1);
            }
        }
        //add node
        private void AddVertex(T? vertex)
        {
            AdjacencyList[vertex] = new HashSet<T>();
        }
    }
```

Node.cs

```
 public Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> ShortestPathFunction<T>(Graph<T> graph, T start)
        {
            //the previous node
            var previous = new Dictionary<T, T>();

            var queue = new Queue<T>();
            queue.Enqueue(start);
           
            //the code looks up the previous node of the destination node
            //and continues looking at all previous nodes until it arrives at the starting node
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var vertex = queue.Dequeue();
                foreach (var neighbor in graph.AdjacencyList[vertex])
                {
                    if (previous.ContainsKey(neighbor))
                        continue;

                    previous[neighbor] = vertex;
                    queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
                }
            }
            // return an IEnumerable<T>, which provides all the vertices that make up the shortest path to get from the starting vertex to the destination vertex
            Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> shortestPath = v => {
                var path = new List<T> { };

                var current = v;
                //var person  = current as Person;
                //var fullName = (person.getFullName().getFirstName() + " " + person.getFullName().getLastName());
                //Console.WriteLine(" current:" + fullName);
                while (!current.Equals(start))
                {
                    path.Add(current);
                    current = previous[current];
                };

                path.Add(start);
                // reverses the list and returns it
                path.Reverse();
                return path;
            };

            return shortestPath;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved its by add on Person class override to Tostring(),

```
 public override String ToString()
 {       
            return getFullName().getFirstName() + " " + getFullName().getLastName();
 }
```

Console: shortest path to aa AA: **aa AA**, and destination is 0